# Are closures causing a leak here?

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I have this simple setup to make an AJAX request and when inspecting memory usage, event listener count and heap use goes up when mashing the button quickly.

Apparently event listener count is expected in Chrome since GC leaves it alone while profiling memory but what about the heap? Am I missing an obvious leak here?

```
function handleResponse(oReq, success_func) {
  return function() {
    try {
      if (oReq.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        if (oReq.status === 200) {
          var data = oReq.responseText;
          success_func(data);
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('Something went wrong: ' + e.description);
    }
  }
}

function makeRequest(name, method, data, success_func) {
  return function() {
    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    oReq.onreadystatechange = handleResponse(oReq, success_func);
    oReq.open(method, 'http://localhost:8080/' + name);
    oReq.send(data);
  }
}

function updateBookList(data) {
  console.log(typeof data);
  document.getElementById('ajax-content').innerHTML = data;
}

document.getElementById('show-books').addEventListener(
  'click', makeRequest('get_books', 'GET', null, updateBookList)
);
```

Comment: I'm not sure if that code would cause a leak. I'm curious why you need closures there? What benefit is gained by `makeRequest` and `handleResponse` returning a closure?

Comment: Just playing around here but the idea was to use them for more requests (on other event handlers for example)

Comment: You can reuse those functions without the closures. Maybe try that and see if your heap problem goes away.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating new structures each time you call a function that returns a function (closure-ish). They will stick around until all the vars and objects within them no longer have any references. GC should clear them out after some time.

Javasccript's "prototype" architecture allows you to create instances off of a "master". This allows you to manage the construction and destruction of things.

Plus it allows you to have multiple, unique instances that don't collide with one-another.

You can leverage the ES6 class structure. Or, here's how it would look as a psuedo "class" off the prototype.

```
this.app = this.app || {};
(function(){

function Req(name, method, data, onSuccess){

    // this is kind of like the constructor
    this.success_func = onSuccess;

    // binding to "this" instance allows the XMLHttpRequest 
    // to trigger the result within the scope of "this" instance. 
    // Otherwise, the "onreadystatechange" method will execute 
    // within the window scope.
    this.handleResponse_bound = this.handleResponse.bind(this);

    this.makeRequest(name, method, data);

}

var p = Req.prototype;

    p.handleResponse = function() {
        try {
          if (this.oReq.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            if (this.oReq.status === 200) {
              var data = this.oReq.responseText;
              this.success_func(data);
              this.cleanup();
            }
          }
        } catch (e) {
          console.log('Something went wrong: ' + e.description);
        }
    }

    p.makeRequest = function(name, method, data) {
        this.oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
        this.oReq.onreadystatechange = this.handleResponse_bound;
        this.oReq.open(method, 'https://jsfiddle.net/' + name);
        this.oReq.send(data);
    }

    p.cleanup = function(){
        this.oReq = null;
        this.success_func = null;
        this.handleResponse_bound = null;
    }

    app.Req = Req;

}());

function updateBookList(data) {
  console.log(typeof data);
  document.getElementById('ajax-content').innerHTML = data;
}

document.getElementById('show-books').addEventListener(
  'click', new app.Req('get_books', 'GET', null, updateBookList)
);
```